# How to add a custom tool to ArcGIS Pro tab/ribbon

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

In ArcMap, we were able to customize the toolbar to add our own Python or ModelBuilder tools. I'm trying to figure out how to do this in ArcGIS Pro but not having any luck. I am able to add a new tab but don't see how I can add tools to it. Basically, I would like to add Python script(s) and ModelBuilder geoprocessing tools to the ArcGIS Pro ribbon interface.  These tools run on the selected features in a map. Is this possible to do in Pro? I understand that we can run these tools from the Catalog pane but I'd like to have the tools available in the ribbon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watch the video I have prepared below, this is how you create custom ribbons with all the tools you want. I show a custom python script tool being added but it could also have been a standard UI tool or other geoprocessing tool.

*Click on image to enlarge*
[image: Customising the interface]

Answer (score 3):

If your tools and script are stored in a toolbox you need to add the toolbox to your project before trying to personnalise (in the catalog pane navigate project>toolbox right click and choose add a toolbox then navigate and select your tool box)

After that when you go to option > customize ribbon the tool should be accessible to add wherever you want.

Alternatively you could navigate to your toolbox, right click on a tool and choose "Add To Analysis Gallery". This will add the tool to to the analysis gallery of the Analysis tab on the ribbon

Read more on this [ArcGIS PRO help page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/customize-arcgis-pro-with-geoprocessing-tools.htm)

Comment: JR, thanks for the reply! The tools are scripts are in a toolbox and adding them to the analysis gallery is great option and what I'm going to be using.  For posterity, I'd like to know how to add the tools to a custom ribbon.  I added the toolbox to the project but under the customize ribbon options, I'm not able to find the tools to add them to the ribbon.

Comment: @Steve then Hornbydd answer has a nice animation on how to do it, you should be able to find the tool, make sure to select the "all geoprocessing tool" option and use the search bar to find your tool